# Advantage of using JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I just went through below link.

http://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/criteria-jpa-2-0-and-database-metamodel-auto-generation-with-maven/

what is the advantage of using `JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In short, having a meta model of your entities available at **compile time** helps you reduce the number of **run-time** errors.

Specifically, with a meta model you may (list is by far not exhaustive)

1. ensure the syntactical correctness of a broader range of queries at compile time (compared to pure JPQL queries)
2. build dynamic, type safe queries
3. (using e.g. Spring Data JPA >= 1.5) take advantage when e.g. specifying the sort order as you can't introduce any typos as in the case with strings

Cf. [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-typesafejpa/) and [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)